# Erro em projeto no Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Tenho instalado o *g++* e o Code::Blocks (Linux-Ubuntu) e criei um projeto e utilizei o código teste do file (`main.cpp`) do Code::Blocks, quando dou `run` aparece uma aba escrito

> It seems that this project has not been built yet.Do you want to build it now?

Se clico em "yes" aparece no *build log*:

> ```
> g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c "/home/gabriel/Área de Trabalho/caramba/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
> g++  -o bin/Debug/caramba obj/Debug/main.o   
> g++: error: obj/Debug/main.o: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
> g++: fatal error: no input files
> compilation terminated.
>
> Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> ```

Se aperto em "no" aparece uma aba (preta) escrito

> Process returned 0 (0x0) execution time: 0.001s Press enter to continue

Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO.
Solucionei mudando o caminho do projeto de  "Área de Trabalho" para outro.(esqueci de acessar minha conta)